# Unit test with enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component in my React-Native application. I have been asked to write a unit test using jest and enzyme for this, but I'm new to unit test. So, how to break this down and write proper tests is beyond my knowledge. Could someone help me with this??

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { Button, Loader, ScreenContainer } from '../../../../../components';

import {
  decodeBase64,
  hasWordsInString,
  setFirstAndFamilyName,
} from '../../../../../library/Utils';

import { url, searchWords, signUpMethods } from '../../../../../config';
import { SIGN_UP_FORM } from '../../../../constants/forms';

// tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
const response = 'some-token';

class MyWebView extends Component {
  state = {
    loaderStatus: true,
  };

  stopLoader = () => {
    this.setState({ loaderStatus: false });
  }

  startLoader = () => {
    this.setState({ loaderStatus: true });
  }

  displayLoader = () => {
    const { loaderStatus } = this.state;
    return loaderStatus && <Loader />;
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation, addFormData, setSignUpMethod } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: url }}
          onLoadStart={() => this.startLoader()}
          onLoad={() => this.stopLoader()}
          onLoadEnd={(syntheticEvent) => {
            const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;

            if (nativeEvent.title === 'Consent Platform') {
              if (hasWordsInString(nativeEvent.url, searchWords)) {
                const { address, ...rest } = decodeBase64(response).data;
                const userName = setFirstAndFamilyName(rest.name);
                rest.firstName = userName.firstName;
                rest.familyName = userName.familyName;

                addFormData({ form: SIGN_UP_FORM, data: { values: { ...rest, ...address } } });
                setSignUpMethod(signUpMethods.MY_INFO);

                navigation.replace('ConfirmName', rest);
              }
            }
          }}
        />

        {this.displayLoader()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyWebView;
```

How can I write some proper unit tests for the above code using jest and enzyme? What are the principles that I have to follow? What makes a unit test a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shallow test, then you can pass in your own dummy data and compare the snapshots, so basically if anyone changes any of your custom components that are used in this component your test will fail

```
import "react-native"
import React from "react"
import { shallow } from "enzyme"

import MyWebView from "../../App/Components/MyWebView"

test("Should render CustomHeader", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyWebView />)
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```